# Update and delete listview row

Tags: c#, wpf

Binding it to the WPF ListView, using `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}"`:

```
   private ObservableCollection<SalesItem> _ProductList = new ObservableCollection<SalesItem>();
            public ObservableCollection<SalesItem> ProductList { get { return _ProductList; } set { _ProductList = value; } }
```

Insert a new row into ListView:

```
SalesItem item = new SalesItem { Picture = product.Picture, ProductName = product.Name, Quantity = 1, TotalPrice = product.Price };
            ProductList.Add(item);
```

Now I want to `update the quantity, and price, if the quantity is zero, remove from list`:

```
  List<SalesItem> salesItems = (from SalesItem items in this.dgProductList.ItemsSource
                                     select items).ToList<SalesItem>();

        foreach (SalesItem salesItem in salesItems)
        {
            if (salesItem.ProductName == cbMultiProductList.Text.Trim())
            {
                // Increase item quantity
                salesItem.Quantity = salesItem.Quantity + 1;
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

---

EDITED:

`SalesItem` is EF Code first model.

Tried this, the problem is he new row will append to the last row:

```
ProductList.Remove(salesItem);
ProductList.Add(salesItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to implement INotyfyPropertyChanged in SalesItem class and Notify for each Property.

Comment: Thanks, how can I implement it whitout touching salesItems model.

Comment: You cant implement it without `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Another way is for you to explicitly check that everytime quantity is set to zero, you should call the foreach loop, which ofcourse is bad progarmming.

Comment: A trick that can work is make your poco class SalesItem properties virtual then I think you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This is a kind of trick

Comment: somethig like this> public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }, will it impact database mapping?

Comment: @ethicallogics tried, something like public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }, it doesn't work.